# How to manually send a log file with specefic count and rate to a server

Tags: command-line, python, logs, syslog

I have a txt log file (syslog format) that i want to send it with specific count(number of lines) and rate(logs per second) to a server (ELK Stack) that parse this logs on port 514.
i see the `logger` command but it hasn't `count` and `rate` option and i need this options because some files are over 100k lines and i should test them in low EPS on udp 514.

Do you have any idea how i can send them? a command, bash script or python are good for me.

Comment: Is simply `split`ting and sending the parts with a delay (use `sleep`) an option?

Comment: There are numerous tools which can count the number of lines in a file, such as matching a '\n'. The "rate" is a little more complex: You need to determine the time of the first and last log entries, and divide the total number of lines logged by the difference. (Note that is **mean average** log entries per period!)